# How can I share a windows network drive to another computer which is in a different network?

Tags: routing, nas, subnet, network-drive, bridge-router

I have a computer (Computer 1) which is in a different subnet than the Network Server. Computer 1 should be able to map a network drive on that server.
There is another computer (Computer 2) which has two network adapters and could be used to establish the connection of both subnets.

I myself have full access to Computer 1 and Computer 2, but not to the server. So it is not possible to use the `add route` command on the server.

[image]

**How can I connect the network drive or use Computer 2 to "re-share" the network drive?**

*Question in German:*
Wie kann ich unter Windows ein Netzlaufwerk zu einem Server verbinden, der in einem anderen Subnetz hängt?
Ein Zwischenrechner mit zwei Netzwerkkarten, der gleichzeitig in beiden Netzen hängt ist vorhanden.
Mein Computer, von dem aus ich das Netzlaufwerk verbinden will hat die IP-Adresse 192.168.1.1
Das Netzlaufwerk befindet sich auf `\\172.20.22.80\MyShare` und ist an Computer 2 mit dem Laufwerksbuchstaben `N:\` verbunden.
Vom Computer 1 aus ist die IP-Adresse 172.20.22.80 nicht erreichbar.

Comment: Is computer 2 already set up as a router? What OS is computer 2 running?

Comment: Setting up Computer 2 as a router only helps me if I also would be able to execute `route add` at the server. But I don't have admin access to the server.
I use Windows 10.

Comment: Well, no, not necessarily; that's the reason for the question.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution using Remote Desktop.
From Computer 2 I start a Remote Desktop session (`mstsc /v:192.168.1.1`).
Before starting the session I click on `Local Resources`, Button `Additional`.
There I select the network drive which Computer 1 should have access to later on.

[image]

After establishing the connection the network drive still seems not connected.
If you type `net use` you can see that it has no drive letter.

[image]

In my case `net use n: \\tsclient\n` assigned the drive properly.
After that I have full access to the network drive as long as Remote Desktop is connected.